# AbsoluteLayout width and height 0px in a Panel. Vaadin

Tags: java, panel, vaadin, scrollable, absolutelayout

First here is the code :

```
  mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
mainLayout.setImmediate(false);

// body
HorizontalSplitPanel panel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();

panel.setFirstComponent(getFirstPanel());
panel.setSplitPosition(10, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
panel.setSecondComponent(getSecondPanel());

// absoluteLayout_2
body = new AbsoluteLayout();
body.addComponent(panel);
body.setImmediate(false);
body.setSizeUndefined();
body.setStyleName("Mybody");
mainLayout.addComponent(body, "top:160.0px;right:1.0px;bottom:45.0px;left:0.0px;");
mainLayout.setSizeUndefined();

Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
mainPanel.setContent(mainLayout);
mainPanel.setSizeFull();
// mainPanel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();
```

when I open the page nothing is displayed. It seems that all my layout that are inside my Panel have size : `width:0px;height:0px;`.

When I change the size as `setSizefull()` for all the layout it works but the panel does not scroll.
Any idea what I forgot in the code above ?

Answer (score 0):

setSizeFull() usually disables scrollbars, use setSizeUndefined() and scrollbars will appear if the component is big enough

Comment: When I use setSizeUndefined() all my components have 0 width and Height. I don't want to give them a fixed size because the content change dynamically.